# PDF form fill with iText error

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a PDF file with some form fields that I need to fill in from Java code. I use iText 2.1.7 library for this, and this code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\igor\\Desktop\\test.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("testout.pdf"), '\0', true);
AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
fields.setField("txtFirstName", "Milan");
stamper.close();
```

and I get this error message:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.checkQName(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2582)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.setName(ElementNSImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.<init>(ElementNSImpl.java:80)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElementNS(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2095)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.XfaForm$Xml2SomDatasets.insertNode(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields.setField(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields.setField(Unknown Source)
at proba.main(proba.java:21)
```

The PDF is not created by me, so I don't know what type of form the file uses (if I understand correctly, there are FDF and XFA forms). Since the PDF is not created by me, I used this tool http://support.persits.com/pdf/demo_formfields.asp to find out the names of the form fields, and it gave me this:

```
applicationPrepaid[0].#pageSet[0].Pagina1[0].txtFirstName[0]
```

[Pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) tool gave me just `txtFirstName` for the field name. I tried both the full name, and just `txtFirstName` and it doesn't work. Help?

Comment: Could you also supply the PDF for inspection? Furthermore, have you also tried that with a current iText version (i.e. a 5.3.x version)? As you are working with an old iText version, that always should be your first test. If it works there, chances are that it either was a bug in the library meanwhile fixed or an anomally in the PDF the library meanwhile has been hardened against.

Comment: I can't supply the PDF :( Company secret. I will try the current version of iText just to see if the problem is in the library, but I can't use it because of the AGPL license.

Comment: The problem persists, even with the current version of iText. I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Unless someone else recognizes the issue and posts a solution, you should try and create a sample PDF you can supply to the public which also exhibits that behavior. Otherwise people will have a hard time trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the fact that you are working with Basic pages.
The name '#pageSet[0' is the one causing the error. I think it's the 'pound' (#) sign that causes the error.